# How to use conditional sql query in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Suppose I have UserDetails table with feilds:

```
UserId, RoleId, UserName, Password, Name, Mobile
```

and UserRole whit:

```
RoleId, RoleName, UserPage
```

I want to get certain information by joining two(or multiple tables) tables. I have query as:

```
SELECT ud.UserId,
    ud.RoleId,
    ud.UserName,
    ud.Password,
    ud.Name,
    ud.Mobile,
    ud.DateOfBirth,
    ur.RoleName,
    ur.UserPage    
FROM UserRole ur join UserDetails ud on ur.RoleId =ud.RoleId and UserName='user1';
```

With JdbcTemplate in spring I am able to get but With hibernate how to get returned values?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem can be solved by using criteria in hibernate or use native SQL query in hibernate to fetch all the data from database.

Comment: can u give an example?

Comment: String sql = "SELECT * FROM TESTEMPLOYEE";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.addEntity(TestEmployee.class);
List results = query.list(); But its is not recommended to use native sql in hibernate. instead you can use HQL . and Hibernate is ORM tool. its help in mapping java object to database and viceversa.. so you need to create pojo and map them properly

Answer (score 1):

Both the ways you can use.

This is sql query:

```
String userName = 'user1'

createSQLQuery("SELECT ud.UserId,
    ud.RoleId,
    ud.UserName,
    ud.Password,
    ud.Name,
    ud.Mobile,
    ud.DateOfBirth,
    ur.RoleName,
    ur.UserPage    
FROM UserRole ur join UserDetails ud on ur.RoleId =ud.RoleId and UserName="+userName)
```

This is hql query:

```
FROM UserRole ur join fetch UserDetails ud  where ud.UserName='user1';
```

use pojo class names as table names and variables in pojo classes as column names

Comment: that means i need to create pojo classes for all tables(which i think resource consuming). I can create pojo of returning value pojo but creating all is not good. Any other solution?

Comment: Without creating pojo classes,how hibernate will works?

Comment: Actually I thought like jdbctemplate we can marshal it, so no need of pojo!